# Pandas: merge_asof method. Substitute with NaNs instead of zero-hold interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to merge the dataframe `df2` to the closest time of `df1`.`df2` has less rows than `df1`.Those are time-series with different sampling times (in seconds):

```
df1
      A  B
1 s  1   2
2 s  2   4
3 s  3   5

df2
       C  D
0.2 s  1  2
1.7 s  2  4

df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)

df3
     A  B  C  D
1 s  1  2  1  2
2 s  2  4  2  4
3 s  3  5  2  4
```

Pandas is filling in the missing rows with a zero-hold interpolation:

but I would like to have NaN instead in the row that is missing like the following:

```
df3
    A  B  C    D
1 s 1  2  1    2
2 s 2  4  2    4
3 s 3  5  Nan  NaN
```

What's the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)` ?

Comment: That woud merge only the index that are common. I think I did not explain well. I'll re-write the question :)

Comment: I try your code and got `MergeError: left can only have one index`. for you working?

Comment: Maybe because I added the 's' to show that those are seconds just in this post. Actually the code that works for me is the following

`df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[2,4,5]}, index = [0,1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'C':[1,2], 'D':[2,4]}, index = [0,1])
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)
`

Comment: At the end I did solved like this:
`df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True); 
for col in df3.columns.values:
      df3.loc[df3[col].duplicated(),col] = np.nan`

Comment: So basically I go through the dataframe again and I substitute duplicates with NaN. I was expecting a more elegant solution but that's fine

Comment: Is possible test `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'C':[1,1], 'D':[1,1]}, index = [0,1])` if your solution with duplicated is correct?

Comment: oh you are right that would not work...